# I cannot start "javascript" debugger in Visual Studio Code (probably, because installed HPC)

Tags: javascript, windows, debugging, visual-studio-code, hpc

Steps to Reproduce:

1. Create folder with app.js file (with several javascript lines).
2. Create default launch.json
3. Run debugger.
   Visual Studio Code doesn't start debugger (seems, tries to execute node.exe from HPC package)
   **DEBUG CONSOLE output:**

   node --debug-brk=37183 --nolazy app.js 
   Node Commands

   Syntax:
       node {operator} [options] [arguments]

   Parameters:
           /? or /help   - Display this help message.
           list          - List nodes or node history or the cluster
           listcores     - List cores on the cluster
           view          - View properties of a node
           online        - Set nodes or node to online state
           offline       - Set nodes or node to offline state
           pause         - Pause node [deprecated]
           resume        - Resume node [deprecated]

   For more information about HPC command-line tools,
   see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=120724.

launch.json content:

`{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Launch",
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/app.js",
            "stopOnEntry": false,
            "args": [],
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "preLaunchTask": null,
            "runtimeExecutable": null,
            "runtimeArgs": [
                "--nolazy"
            ],
            "env": {
                "NODE_ENV": "development"
            },
            "externalConsole": false,
            "sourceMaps": false,
            "outDir": null
        },
        {
            "name": "Attach",
            "type": "node",
            "request": "attach",
            "port": 5858,
            "address": "localhost",
            "restart": false,
            "sourceMaps": false,
            "outDir": null,
            "localRoot": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "remoteRoot": null
        },
        {
            "name": "Attach to Process",
            "type": "node",
            "request": "attach",
            "processId": "${command.PickProcess}",
            "port": 5858,
            "sourceMaps": false,
            "outDir": null
        }
    ]
}`

- VSCode Version:

[image]

- OS Version: windows7

Comment: Have you tired talking to me about this? You're more likely to get an answer from them...

Comment: Could you help me to understand the issue and start javascript debugging in visual studio code?

Comment: SO isn't for this sort of thing. I'd suggest you log the bug with the Microsoft Visual Studio Code team.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VSC developer suggests next possible ways:

> - change your PATH so that the correct 'node' will be found first. You
>     can verify which node is found on the path by running `where node` in a
>     command prompt.
> - find the correct 'node' on your system and then add a
>     `runtimeExecutable` attribute with the absolute path to your 'node' to
>     your launch config

I updated launch.json file and it solved the issue

```
"runtimeExecutable": "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe",
```

https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/11540